# VHDL Components work perfectly separately; having issues connecting them in an upper entity

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx

### Background

The goal is to design a watchdog timer (WDT) using structural modeling using Xilinx. The WDT received a Start trigger which initiates the counter, counts for 59 clock cycles, produces a one-clock interval pulse to signal Reset condition and resets to 0. So I made the following diagram in photoshop to illustrate the components and how they should be connected. WDT is the upper entity.

[Schematic and Overall Concept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IzzD.png)

- CLKN is a negative edge clock shared across the SR-ff and the WDT (as well as the counter and the T-ffs in the counter)
- Counter is a 6bit binary counter made out of T-FF

  - Six T-FFs cascaded where the input to the first ff's clock line is the system clock and the clock input for the remaining ffs is the Q from the previous T-ff so the ffs toggle at every 2i where i = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 so it creates a binary counter
- The 6 fan-in and gate is a custom and gate made so that the output is 1 only when the sequence 111010 is the input (111010 = 58; 0->58 = 59 clock cycles)

  - When the output = 1, it resets the SR ff which resets the counter and the WDT
- The 2 fan-in and gate ensures that the counter runs only when Q = 1 and the CLKN is asserted

  - Q = 1 when S = 1 when the Start trigger is asserted. The trigger stays high until the WDT resets
- The outer thicker frame represents the WDT

  - START maps to Start
  - CLKN maps to CLKN
  - Reset_Signal maps to Send_Reset

### What I have tried

- I have tested every component separately and they work accordingly (code for them listed in the end)
- Have tried switching std_logic to bit to avoid values other than 0 and 1 -- didn't work; switched back to std_logic
- Initialized every port and signal possible to avoid uninitialized values issues -- worked some times for a certain combination but I could never duplicate it
- I have debugged the components and the signals in the ISim waveform screen

[Screenshot of Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XeY0.png)

- Disregard the first 100 ns
- The SR ff is not producing a q or qnot output even though it shows a constant value of 1 and 0; notice there are no wave forms for those two outputs as well as R
- This issue propagates to the 2 fan-in AND gate which produces a constant output of 1 even when the inputs are not 11; it does not read the Q output from the SR ff; since the output is a constant 1, there is no transition thus no clock into the counter
- The issue seems to be due to portmapping but I don't really see what I'm doing wrong. I mean, it must be because I've tried everything else (as far as code is concerned) and I've isolated it to the portmapping.
- There are no syntax errors
  I honestly don't know what to do anymore. I've been stuck on this for about 7 hours now and I'm honestly going crazy (the lack of sleep doesn't help).

### Code (essential sections)

## SR FF

```
entity SR_FF is
    Port ( S : in  std_logic;
           R : in  std_logic;
              CLKN : in std_logic;
              QNOT : out std_logic := '1';
           Q : out  std_logic := '0');
end SR_FF;

architecture Behavioral of SR_FF is

begin

    process(CLKN)

    variable imm: std_logic := '0';
    begin

        if (falling_edge(CLKN)) then
            if (S = '0' AND R = '0') then
                imm := imm; --no change
            elsif (S = '0' AND R = '1') then
                imm := '0';
            elsif (S = '1' AND R = '0') then
                imm := '1';
            else
                NULL;
            end if;
        end if;

        Q <= imm;
        QNOT <= not imm;

    end process;
```

## T FF

```
entity T_FF is
    Port ( T : in  STD_LOGIC;
           CLKN : in  STD_LOGIC;
              Reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           Q : out  STD_LOGIC := '0';
           Qnot : out  STD_LOGIC := '1');
end T_FF;

architecture Behavioral of T_FF is

begin

    process(CLKN, Reset)

    variable imm: std_logic := '0';

    begin
    if (Reset = '0') then
        if (falling_edge(CLKN)) then
            if (T = '0') then
                imm := imm; --no change
            elsif (T = '1') then
                imm := not imm; --toggle
            else
                NULL;
            end if;
        end if;
    else
        imm := '0';
    end if;

    Q <= imm;
    Qnot <= not imm;

    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

## SIX BIT COUNTER

```
entity six_bit_counter is
    Port ( CLKN : in  STD_LOGIC;
              RESET : in STD_LOGIC;
           COUNT : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0) := "000000");
end six_bit_counter;

architecture Structural of six_bit_counter is

component T_FF
    Port ( T : in  STD_LOGIC;
           CLKN : in  STD_LOGIC;
              Reset : in STD_LOGIC;
           Q : out  STD_LOGIC;
           Qnot : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

component OR_two
    Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC;
           B : in  STD_LOGIC;
           C : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

signal clk_trigger : std_logic_vector (4 downto 0) := "00000";
signal temp_count : std_logic_vector (5 downto 0) := "000000";

begin

T0: T_FF port map (T => '1', Reset => RESET, CLKN => CLKN, Q => temp_count(0), Qnot => open);
T1: T_FF port map (T => '1', Reset => RESET, CLKN => clk_trigger(0), Q => temp_count(1), Qnot => open);
T2: T_FF port map (T => '1', Reset => RESET, CLKN => clk_trigger(1), Q => temp_count(2), Qnot => open);
T3: T_FF port map (T => '1', Reset => RESET, CLKN => clk_trigger(2), Q => temp_count(3), Qnot => open);
T4: T_FF port map (T => '1', Reset => RESET, CLKN => clk_trigger(3), Q => temp_count(4), Qnot => open);
T5: T_FF port map (T => '1', Reset => RESET, CLKN => clk_trigger(4), Q => temp_count(5), Qnot => open);

//used to duplicate signals; same signal is applied to the clock_input of the flip flops as well as the counter output value
O0: OR_two port map (A => '0', B =>  temp_count(0), C => clk_trigger(0));
O1: OR_two port map (A => '0', B =>  temp_count(1), C => clk_trigger(1));
O2: OR_two port map (A => '0', B =>  temp_count(2), C => clk_trigger(2));
O3: OR_two port map (A => '0', B =>  temp_count(3), C => clk_trigger(3));
O4: OR_two port map (A => '0', B =>  temp_count(4), C => clk_trigger(4));

//signal mapped to counter output
O5: OR_two port map (A => '0', B =>  temp_count(0), C => COUNT(0));
O6: OR_two port map (A => '0', B =>  temp_count(1), C => COUNT(1));
O7: OR_two port map (A => '0', B =>  temp_count(2), C => COUNT(2));
O8: OR_two port map (A => '0', B =>  temp_count(3), C => COUNT(3));
O9: OR_two port map (A => '0', B =>  temp_count(4), C => COUNT(4));
OA: OR_two port map (A => '0', B =>  temp_count(5), C => COUNT(5));


end Structural;
```

## WDT

```
entity WDT is
    Port ( CLKN : in STD_LOGIC;
              Start : in STD_LOGIC;
           Reset_Signal : out  STD_LOGIC);
end WDT;

architecture Structural of WDT is

component SR_FF is
    Port ( S : in  std_logic;
           R : in  std_logic;
              CLKN : in std_logic;
              QNOT : out std_logic;
           Q : out  std_logic);
end component;


component six_bit_counter
    Port ( CLKN : in  STD_LOGIC;
              RESET : in STD_LOGIC;
           COUNT : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0));
end component;

component AND_six
    Port ( A_IN : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (5 downto 0);
           A_OUT : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

component AND_two
    Port ( A_IN : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
           A_OUT : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

component OR_two
    Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC;
           B : in  STD_LOGIC;
           C : out  STD_LOGIC);
end component;

signal temp_count : std_logic_vector (5 downto 0) := "000000";
signal send_reset : std_logic := '0'; --coming out of and_six
signal q_temp : std_logic := '0';
signal clk_counter : std_logic := '0';
signal q_not_temp : std_logic := '0';

begin
--58 = 111010

SRFF1: SR_FF port map (S => Start, R =>send_reset, CLKN => CLKN, Q => q_temp, QNOT => q_not_temp);
A1: AND_two port map (A_IN(0) => CLKN, A_IN(1) => q_temp, A_OUT => clk_counter);
C1: six_bit_counter port map (CLKN => clk_counter, Reset => send_reset, COUNT => temp_count);
A2: AND_six port map (A_IN => temp_count, A_OUT => send_reset);
//used to duplicate Reset signal which is mapped to the interal reset signal to reset the counter and SR ff as well as mapped to the WDT output to demonstrate the counter reached its threshold
OR1: OR_two port map (A => '0', B => send_reset, C => Reset_Signal);

end Structural;
```

I appreciate any help/ideas/suggestions. I'd rather not start over because I have already invested so much time into this but I will if I have to.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post your testbench code. Add the counter outputs. Also, test R too so you can see Q and notQ active in the sim. Also, which sim are you using? It looks like it fails to correctly draw signals with no transitions. Basically it looks like you are good to start debugging.

Comment: Looks like college homework as no one in their right mind would create a 6 bit counter this way.   Instead we would use a single register whose type is either integer or unsigned and down count from 59 to 0 and after 0, reload with 59.   The whole purpose of the abstraction provided by HDLs is to simplify things like this.   Certainly there are other ways to talk about structural code rather than suffering through this.   Good luck.   As with any  engineering project though - your job is to solve the problem - and as a student unfortunately by following the directions given.